# Merging two identical select queries

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have two identical sql queries and i want to merge the results.
The first one is:

```
SELECT USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO 
FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE 
WHERE FRIENDLIST.USER_ID=". $userID ." 
  AND APPROVED='YES' 
  AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID 
  AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
```

The second one is:

```
SELECT USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO 
FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE 
WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID=". $userID ."
  AND APPROVED='YES' 
  AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID 
  AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
```

I tried with union but i get an empty result instead of 2 rows for $userID=2 for example.

```
SELECT USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO
FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE 
WHERE FRIENDLIST.USER_ID=". $userID ." 
  AND APPROVED='YES' 
  AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID 
  AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID 
UNION
SELECT USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO 
FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE
WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID=". $userID ." 
  AND APPROVED='YES' 
  AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID 
  AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
```

Any ideas??

Comment: To be clear -- you are saying the each of the individual queries works for $userID=2 (i.e. yields 2 rows), but the UNION gives you an empty resultset?

Comment: Each of them return 1 row..with union i expect 2 but i get zero.

Comment: At the very least you need `UNION ALL`; otherwise the duplicates will be removed (making the operation pointless).

Comment: Well, UNION is implicitly UNION DISTINCT -- so issuing the exact same query twice would give you 1 row, not 2 -- you'll need to use UNION ALL to get duplicates.

Comment: I want distinct results. I just noticed that from the $userID's value that i wanted the results the approved was 'NO'. I transferred the script in another databases with different values! Thanks guys for the answers! I need some sleep!!

Answer (score 0):

I would combine them like this:

```
SELECT USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO 
FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE 
WHERE (FRIENDLIST.USER_ID=". $userID ." or FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID=". $userID .")
  AND APPROVED='YES' 
  AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID 
  AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
```

Well, not strictly true.  I would use proper syntax for the joins and use short aliases for the tables:

```
SELECT u.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO 
FROM FRIENDLIST f join
     USER u
     on u.USER_ID = f.USER_ID  join
     USER_PROFILE up
     on u.USER_ID = up.USER_ID
WHERE (f.USER_ID=". $userID ." or f.FRIEND_ID=". $userID .") and
      APPROVED='YES'
```

The `union` is another, less efficient method for doing the same thing.  If the result set is empty, it is because no one matches the criteria.